# OneM2M: Changing MN-CSE configurations from IN-CSE

Tags: notifications, iot, m2m, onem2m

In oneM2M, I want to update the MN-CSE configurations by sending the command from IN-CSE to MN-CSE. How can I achieve this?

My Approach: I am thinking of creating an AE on MN-CSE say CONFIG-AE. Every time I want to change anything, I will create a new Content Instance inside the container of CONFIG-AE. The container will have a subscription with the CONFIG-AE resource as the notificationURL. Now when we add new content instance, the request will be redirected to the POA (point of access) of CONFIG-AE. The POA will be basically an IPE implementation which will further process the action. Is the approach correct?

```
CONFIG-AE (POA=an IPE implementation)
        |
        |   
        --------Container
                    |
                    |
                    --------Subscription (notificationURL=path of CONFIG-AE)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach would work. Any AE that has the permissions to create a content instance under the container can set configuration data this way. The CONFIG-AE in your example would then need to apply the new configuration accordingly. I am not sure, though, why this AE would be an IPE? With what would it provide interworking functionality?

Nevertheless, you should also have a look at TS-0001, clause 10.2.8 "Device management" and the whole of TS-0022, "Field Device Configuration". Here, oneM2M specifies specific management resources to manage nodes in a oneM2M deployment. This might look like an overkill at first but since the resource types defined there are well aligned with other management technologies this might be worth the efforts.

Depending on your infrastructure you might also want to look at TS-0005 "Management Enablement (OMA)" and TS-0006 "Management Enablement (BBF)" in case you are working with remote management technologies from OMA or BBF.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Andreas, its very useful.